# What is negative squared euclidean distance?

Tags: math, euclidean-distance

It is described as `-||xi-xy||^2`.

So for 2 two dimensional points do I code it like this?

```
- ((x1-x2) + (y1-y2))^2
```

or

```
-( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 )
```

or

```
-(sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 ))
```

or some other way?

Comment: You mean ||xi - yi||, not ||xi - xy||.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct answer is

```
-( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 )
```

The mathematical description is accurate, but not useful for implementation.  It's stated as the square of the distance between the points, which if implemented directly would be something like:

```
len = sqrt( (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2) );
result = -( len*len );
```

which can simplified to

```
result = -( (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2) );
```

which is your #2.

Comment: There's really no reason for the `sqrt` and the latter `-` operation on the square. Just apply `-` to the sum of the squares (after eliminating `sqrt`) as that value will always be positive.

Answer (score 1):

The third is the negative of the distance. The second appears to be the negative of the square of the distance.